# How to get network bandwidth or upload speed using gstreamer

Tags: upload, gstreamer, bandwidth

How I can get the bandwidth value at server side using gstreamer for
video streaming? So, I can set the bitrate according to the bandwidth or upload speed.

Currently, I am using this pipeline at server side: 
v4l2src-> x264enc->h264pay->rtpbin->udpsink RTP port=5000

I am getting the RTCP details using at server side and client side.
  /* get the right session */
  g_signal_emit_by_name (rtpbin, "get-internal-session", sessid, &session);

/* get the internal source the SSRC allocated to us, the receiver */
    g_object_get (session, "internal-source", &isrc, NULL);